# How can I create an instance of an ObjectSet?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework, objectset

I am making DAO unit tests in my project and I have a problem using the `ObjectSet` class. I have to create a new `ObjectSet` but in order to do this, I must not connect to the DB.  So I can not use the `BusinessModelContainer`'s `CreateObjectSet()` method.  Is there is a way to create the `ObjectSet` without it?

The unit test code is like this:

```
var mock = new Mock<IBusinessModelContainerWrapper>();  
ObjectSet<Student> expectedStudent = ???;  // how can I get an instance here?
StudentDao studentDao = new StudentDao(mock.Object);  

expectedStudent.Add(someObj);  
mock.Setup(c => c.Students).Returns(expectedStudent);  

Assert.AreEqual(someObj, studentDao.GetByQuery(...));
```

Answer (score 12):

What are you testing? You should not need instance of real `ObjectSet` in your unit test unless you are unit testing EF code. Use mock of `IObjectSet` instead. There is no way to get instance of `ObjectSet` without the context.

Answer (score 3):

```
DAL.Moles.MDALEntities.Constructor = (a) => { };
DALEntities db = new DALEntities(); //Object Context

System.Data.Objects.Moles.MObjectContext.AllInstances.CreateObjectSet<ObjectSetType>(
(a) => { return new System.Data.Objects.Moles.MObjectSet<ObjectSetType>(); }
);

ObjectSet<ObjectSetType> dbList = db.CreateObjectSet<ObjectSetType>();
```